# VMware ESXi multiple I/O latency warnings

Tags: vmware-esxi, hard-drive

VMware ESXi 5.1.0 server showing multiple warning events:

> Device mpx.vmhba1:C0:T0:L0 performance has deteriorated. I/O latency
>   increased from average  value of 3913 microseconds to 530954
>   microseconds. warning 9/07/2014 10:55:20 AM localhost.domain.com.au

mpx.vmhba1:C0:T0:L0 is a local disk.

Can someone please advise on how to resolve? Does this local disk need scanning for errors? If so, how do I perform a scan?

Comment: I have seen this with iSCSI devices where the SAN controller firmware was out of date.  What's the make/model of the local disk?  What controller is it connected to?  ESXi patches up to date?  Hardware you are using on VMware's HCL?

Comment: What type of server, array controller and disks are involved here?

Comment: The server is a HP ProLiant DL 380 G5. The only hard drive details I can find under vSphere are: Local VMware Disk (mpx.vmhba1:C0:T0:L0). Is it possible to obtain further details on the hard drives & array controller via SSH console?